# How to find the pid of the process which has deleted a file?

Tags: process, rm

I am working on a project related to VM migration. Sometimes the VM image will disappear and I just want to know who the culprit is. I tried strace on suspicious processes but to no avail.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to trace unlink system call on every process instead of just one but I guess there is no easy way to do this...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally I found the answer [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html).

The Linux Audit daemon will do the trick.

```
sudo auditctl -w /path/to/somefile -p wra
```

and then

```
ausearch -f /path/to/somefile -i
```

Comment: nice, but how does it affect performance?

Comment: @vartec not too much, after tuning https://linux-audit.com/tuning-auditd-high-performance-linux-auditing/

Comment: This article explains how to use `auditd` in a very noob-friendly way: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-track-changes/

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the PID of a process, which has some file open using `lsof`.

Once file is closed and deleted, you cannot get that information.

BTW. Keep in mind, that deleting a file is operation on directory it's in, not on a file itself.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no need to open a file to delete it. At least for example "strace rm some-file" output doesn't show that rm command first open the file and then delete it. So I guess lsof is not helpful.

Comment: Read the last sentence of my answer

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest an alternative with [sysdig](http://www.sysdig.org/) as the answers above are aging. Let display the `pid` and `name` of the processes that delete the file `/tmp/test`. First we create the file with `touch /tmp/test`. Then we start `sysdig` with the following filter:

```
$ sudo sysdig -p'%proc.pid,%proc.name' '(evt.type=unlinkat and (evt.arg.name=test or evt.arg.name=/tmp/test)) or (evt.type=unlink and evt.arg.path=/tmp/test)'
```

`unlinkat(2)` requires an `or` filter if the *path* (e.g. `evt.arg.name`)  may be *relative*. To handle both `unlink` (which calls `unlink(2)`) and `rm` (which calls `unlinkat(2)` in its GNU version), the filter should match both syscalls.

`sysdig` should be running when a process deletes the file. Then when we execute such commands:

```
$ unlink /tmp/test
$ touch /tmp/test
$ rm /tmp/test
$ cd /tmp; touch test; rm test
```

It will displays such an output:

```
11380,unlink
11407,rm
11662,rm
```

Please refer to the [sysdig user guide](http://www.sysdig.org/wiki/sysdig-user-guide/) for an explanation about filtering and output.

As the filter is pretty long, I found it convenient to write a chisel. It is a lua script that is associated with a `sysdig` command:

```lua
description = "displays processes that delete a file"
short_description = "spy file deletion"
category = "files"

args = 
{
    {
        name = "path", 
        description = "the path of the file to monitor", 
        argtype = "string"
    },
}

function on_set_arg(name, val)
    path = val
    return true
end

function on_init()
    local filename = path
    for i in string.gmatch(path, "[^/]+") do
        filename = i
    end
    chisel.set_event_formatter("%proc.pid\t%proc.name")
    chisel.set_filter(
        "(evt.type=unlinkat and (evt.arg.name=" .. path .. " or \
                             evt.arg.name=" .. filename .. ")) or \
     (evt.type=unlink and evt.arg.path=" .. path .. ")")
    return true
end
```

Feel free to comment and improve it. You can put the lua script in a `spy_deletes.lua` file inside a directory and execute `sysdig` in this directory to make the chisel available. When typing `sudo sysdig -cl` you will see it as:

```
Category: files
---------------
spy_deletes         spy file deletion
```

Now you can call it:

```
$ sudo sysdig -c spy_deletes /tmp/test
```

And in another terminal type:

```
$ touch test; unlink test
$ touch test; unlink /tmp/test
$ touch test; rm test
$ touch test; rm /tmp/test
```

It will output:

```
16025   unlink
16033   unlink
16041   rm
16049   rm
```

The `unlinkat` filter would deserve to be more accurate and only match the absolute path. This would require to retrieve the fd of the directory passed to `unlinkat(2)`.

Comment: I have no output with your command.

Comment: I was typing `rm /tmp/test` in another terminal. I edited my answer to make it clearer.